# What's a better way to have two short divisions of text, one on the left and one on the right?

Tags: html, css

In my website, there are headings that often need some explanatory text (e.g. a date) to their right. My current solution is to have the `<div>` right before the `<h1>` or `<h2>`, so that the header still clears the right-floating div.

[image: "thing on right" comes before "thing on left"]

This is the only CSS I've churned out so far:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    display: block; width: auto;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

And its accompanying HTML:

```
<div class="right">thing on right</div>
<h2>thing on left</h2>
```

Is there a way to format a header and a `<div>` to the right that wouldn't require them to be written backwards? And preferably without *relying* on the right-aligned div to be there, or *relying* on there to be an extra element wrapped around, or before or after, these two?

It seems really awkward that the only simple implementation is so backwards.

Comment: Are these elements in a container of some sort?

Comment: @DerekS They're in an extra `<div>` right now, which is in turn inside `<body>` , if that helps. .

Comment: @DerekS Oops, I misunderstood the question. These elements are alongside many others, although given the comments maybe they SHOULD be in their own containier.

Answer (score 2):

Given your additional comment of the two elements being wrapped in a div, you could do the use table displays to achieve this quite easily, **[(See fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/u4CeP/)**:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table-row;
}

h1,
.additional {
    display: table-cell;
}

.additional {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When you consider that the `float` solutions don't include the additional *clearfix* required then the markup is near identical.

Answer (score 1):

One example I've found uses left-dev, then right-div; and floats both of them to the left. It also uses width: percentages to position the right div far to the side, without depending on its existence. Does that help at all?

You could also try using the "flex-box" spec in CSS3, although this would reduce how many versions of Internet Explorer you can target. (Hey, even Microsoft doesn't support Windows XP anymore!)

Comment: This MIGHT actually be helpful, unless a line is too long or some other nonsense. If I were working with large chunks of content, you'd probably be right on the money.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `<span>` for right content e.g.

```
<h2>thing on left<span>thing on right</span></h2>
```

---

```
h2 span {
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/VxqW7/)**

Comment: Okay, that's so stupidly simple... possibly my favorite answer so far. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidIsNotHere: The only downside of this is that the nested `span` will need to *undo* all of the properties which it doesn't need, rather than a separate element solution which *adds* them. And you need to clear after the `h2`. In some situations this will be better, in some it won't, it really depends on the situation :)

Comment: If few CSS properties like `font-size` & `font-weight` on nested span are bigger problem than wrapper div on every heading, ok...this has downside ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'de prefere to use display: inline-blocks

CSS:

```
/* replace wrapper with your container class */
.wrapper>h2 { 
    display: inline-block; 
}
.wrapper>div { 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>thing on left</h2>
    <div>thing on right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note this will not align the contents of the second element to the right.

Comment: True, it will just put them side by side. I should have read the question better.

Comment: Too much editing and it would look like another answer -- even if wrong, it's interesting. P.S. `display:table-cell` should left-align things too, as long as they weren't floated.